# Why does xargs output results with new line characters?

Tags: find, xargs

When executing the command `find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*/[a-zA-Z]+\.txt`, it returns the following results.

```
./testfile.txt
./testread.txt
```

In contrast the the command `find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*/[a-zA-Z]+\.txt' -print0` outputs `./testfile.txt./testread.txt` as a single line which to my understanding the flag `-print0` strips/replaces `\n` with `NUL` or `\0` as uses these as separators.

When the latter command and arguments are passed to `xargs` as follows `find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*/[a-zA-Z]+\.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 -i echo {}`, it displays

```
./testfile.txt
./testread.txt
```

I have assumed that `'{}'` subsequent to `echo` isn't needed since the flag `-print0` is used and characters such as spaces are processed without errors.

The commands below all generate a single line.

- `find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*/[a-zA-Z]+\.txt' -print0 | xargs -0`
- `find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*/[a-zA-Z]+\.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 echo`

Why does `xargs` with `{}` return the results with new lines characters?

If `{}` appends a new line character, why use couple it with a command e.g. `echo {}`?

Comment: It would be helpful to have guidance as to why the question was down voted? What about the question needs to be clarified or alternatively needs to be improved?

Comment: It does not. Echo added the newline character.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor - I thought it may since both echo and other commands such as `ls` do as well however it is unclear to why since without `-i` and `{}` does not e.g. `find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*/[a-zA-Z]+\.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 echo`.

Comment: In that case `xargs` is passing multiple args to a single `echo` then echo is concatenating them into a single line with spaces between (that is what echo does). Try this variant with `ls -l`. You get separate lines (because that is what `ls` does.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor - Yes, I am aware that `echo` concatenates the output with spaces. To clarify, does the use of '{}' append a new line character? If yes, why use it instead of only `echo` as opposed to `echo {}`?

Comment: @Kusalananda - Please let me know there is anything I should do to improve the question. Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For GNU `xargs`, the `-i` option is (deprecated and) the same as `-I {}`.  This means "replace the occurrence of the string `{}` in the utility with one item from standard input, then run the utility and repeat with the next item from standard input".

Your utility invocation is `echo {}`, and you pass two things to `xargs`. This means calling `echo` twice, each time with one of the items read from standard input.  Each invocation of `echo` outputs a trailing newline (this is a feature of `echo`).

Without `echo {}` and `-i`, `xargs` will collect as many items as possible from standard input and output them as if it had called `echo` with all of them at once.

In short, `xargs` does not add a newline, `echo` does. It does this because you call it multiple times.

Example (with `-t` added so that `xargs` shows what it does):

```
$ printf 'file1\nfile2\n' | xargs -t -I {} echo {}
echo file1
file1
echo file2
file2
```

```
$ printf 'file1\nfile2\n' | xargs -t echo
echo file1 file2
file1 file2
```

Comment: And `xargs -I {}` is the same as `xargs -L1 -I {}`

Comment: @Kusalananda - To clarify, does `xargs -I echo {}` mean that `echo file` `echo file`? If yes, if invoked as simply `xargs echo`, why is there no trailing new line?

Comment: @Ryan Without `-i` or `-I {}`, `xargs` will collect as many arguments as possible and call the given utility with all of these at once. Calling `echo` with multiple strings will not put a newline between them. You may want to see what `xargs` actually does. You can do this with its `-t` option.

Comment: @Kusalananda - If I have understood you correctly that `xargs echo` translates into `xargs echo file1 file2 file3` as a single process whereas `xargs -I echo {}` is transformed as `echo file1` `echo file2` and `echo file3` where each is processed as a new command and thus a new line. If yes, I assume the benefit of `-I` is when `{}` needs to be used in between commands such as `mv {} /Downloads`. If no, there is no requirement for `-I`.

Comment: @Ryan That is a correct understanding. You would use `-I {}` in situations where you need to run a command once for each thing read from standard input, separately.

Comment: @Kusalananda - What would be an example of such a need?

Comment: @Ryan You provided one yourself: `mv {} destdir` (although with GNU `mv`, this could be rewritten as `mv -t destdir` which could take any number of additional arguments).

Comment: @Kusalananda - Thanks. My understanding is that `-t` is not an explicit flag. If it is otherwise, please let me know.

Comment: @Ryan I'm not sure whether you mean the `-t` option for `xargs` or for `mv`, or what you mean by "explicit".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103468/discussion-between-ryan-and-kusalananda).

Answer (score 1):

The newline characters are being added by `echo`, **not** by `xargs`.

The difference when you use `-i` is because this option forces `-L 1` (one line, or one null separated field per command). Thus `echo` in run once for each input field, and thus a newline character between fields (`echo` normally adds a newline character when it has finished).

Without `-i`, and thus without `-L 1`, each echo receives more field, thus most fields are separated with a space (echo concatenation its arguments, separated by a space).